# How to insert image into an XML document just like in HTML?

Tags: html, css, xml, web

Just practicing XML, the regular img tags did'nt work, is it possible to insert image to an XML document like in HTML?

Comment: Please be more clear. What kind of "XML document" are you talking about?

Comment: Hello @Coder111, I think you're confusing XHTML and XML. XHTML is a strict version of HTML, but XML is a markup language for making machine-readable files

Answer (score 1):

XML is a textual data format, a markup language that defines a set of rules for encoding documents. There is no regular "img" tag, because it's you who is in charge of naming your tags, according to how you want to structure your data.
To embed images, you can encode it in base64, or store the path to your local or distant file for instance.